# How to remove ListView hover effect when using an ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Could not find a solution that works for my scenario where I have a ListView with an ItemTemplate like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewHover.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace ListViewHover
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Items = new List<Item> { new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3) };
        }

        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public Item(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get => $"This is Item number {Id}"; }
    }
}
```

If you run this the list has the default hover-effect. I need this to go away so the only effect is the background changing when an item is selected.

I've tried to specify the ItemContainerStyle and also applying style triggers on the ListViewItems but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You should rewrite ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: Can you use ItemsControl?

Comment: Could you perhaps make an example of the ItemContainerStyle? Because as I've written, I've tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I will write this

Comment: Please post your attempted solution (`ItemContainerStyle`) and explain us what exactly didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use ItemsControl?

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:Item">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

[image]

If you want to write the ListView and rewrite the ItemContainerStyle that you can use this code.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- set SelectedBackgroundColor to Transparent when you do not need the background in selected items -->
    <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#00FFFFFF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFB2A3A2</Color>

    <!-- set the MouseOverColor to Transparent when you do not need the effect in the unselected items -->
    <Color x:Key="MouseOverColor" >#00FFFFFF</Color>

    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle"
           TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Padding="2"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                            Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" >
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                 Value="{StaticResource MouseOverColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                 Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                 Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:Item">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The core code is changing the SelectedBackgroundColor to Transparent when you do not need the background in the selected items and changing the MouseOverColor to Transparent when you do not need the effect in the unselected items.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates

Comment: Well not out of the box because I need to select an item and change the background, bind etc.

Comment: ItemContainerStyle to the rescue, awesome! Now I need to dig into why and how, but it works like I want it to. Thanks!